# Grails way to prevent bad request "ids" on url

Tags: url, grails, plugins

Like here in stackoverflow if i force put bad characters on URL in id place it redirects you to a page error. I would like to know if with Grails it has some kind of plugin for prevent id like: "123$#3" or an easy way because i have a lot of actions and do something like below dont seems to be the best way:

---

```
def find = {   

     def val = OwnStringUtilsClass.verify(params.id)
     val ? Book.get(val) : response.sendError(404)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following in `grails-app/conf/UrlMappings.groovy`:

```
  "/$controller/$action?/$id?"{
          constraints {
                    id(matches:/\d*/)
              }
      }
```

This will ensure that the `id` is numeric.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a [controller filter](http://www.grails.org/Filters).